# How to notify IAM Users when Password/Access Keys expire?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, passwords, amazon-iam

I am trying to find a solution to notify all AWS IAM Users if their Password and Access Keys expire. Is there a way to do it via console or with some Python script?

The IAM User should get a mail at least before a week when their IAM Password and access keys expire.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that runs on a regular schedule (you can do this with scheduled Lambda, for example).

Call [get_credential_report](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_credential_report) to see how long till IAM passwords will expire and call [list_access_keys](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_access_keys) to see when access keys were created (and hence calculate when they need to be rotated).

Note: the AWS Management Console warns IAM users when they are within 15 days of password expiration.

Comment: I am sorry, couldn't get on it.. Could You please guide more on this..

Comment: get_credential_report() get the report in the csv format only.. I want to send notification/mail to the IAM Users whose passwords are about to expire in a week.

Answer (score 0):

For the passwords, you could use the [`GetCredentialReport`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialReport.html) API call. In there you will find the `password_next_rotation`:

> When the account has a password policy that requires password rotation, this field contains the date and time, in ISO 8601 date-time format, when the user is required to set a new password. The value for the AWS account (root) is always not_supported.

Using this information, you could write a script to send those emails (assuming you have tagged your users with their email addresses in IAM)

It's available in `boto3`: [`get_credential_report()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_credential_report).

Note that access keys do not expire.

Answer (score 0):

This is my contribution with a simple bash script that can help to achieve that easier

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# VERSION 1.0.0

export REPORT=$(aws iam get-credential-report --query "Content" --output text | base64 -d)
export USERS=($(echo $REPORT | awk -F "\"*,\"*" 'NR>2 {print $1"|"$7}'))

for user in $USERS;
  do
    export USER=$(echo $user | awk -F '[|]' '{print $1}')
    export EXPIRATION_DATE=$(echo $user | awk -F '[|]' '{print $2}')

    if [[ "$EXPIRATION_DATE" != "N/A" ]] && [ "$EXPIRATION_DATE" != "not_supported" ]; then
        echo "Checking user $USER with expiration date -$EXPIRATION_DATE-"    
        let REM_DAYS=\($(date +%s -d $EXPIRATION_DATE)-$(date +%s)\)/86400
        echo $REM_DAYS
    fi
  done
```

This is my link where I will post newer version if I found some error/improvements https://gist.github.com/andresjz/048891dc6e92c19bc3346c00513232f3#file-get_accounts_expirations-sh-L5